# FTE should not pick the file until unless file is ready for transfer

Tags: websphere-mq-fte

I came across the scenario where FTE is transferring file before files is ready. Basically the issue is MQ is writing the file and FTE picked the file in between and transfer the files before it got complete.

Answer (score 0):

I think the MQ/application that is writing the file must have released the lock on the file which indicates file writing is done. So FTE might have picked up the file for transfer.

Comment: Thanks Shashi. What I understand is FTE wont pick files until unless MQ release lock.